# My svg draw on scroll from middle, I want to start from top

Tags: javascript, svg

```
<svg id="route "xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="712px" height="2018px" viewBox="0 0 712 2018" class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">
<path id="triangle" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="5" d="M-3.215,2030.921
c8.816-23.698,1.293-50.813,11.855-74.949c13.239-30.25,36.07-52.368,63.675-68.83c39.115-23.327,200.048-39.239,241.599-39.239 c85.812,0,169.935-1.5,251.667-17.933c74.616-15.001,99.381-62.185,103.271-132.082c7.2-129.404-162.375-182.709-261.459-210.021 c-66.561-18.348-117.888-37.01-175.849-77.998c-40.217-28.439-112.694-81.217-96.218-141.023
c35.773-129.859,256.615-74.554,349.684-99.021c67.062-17.629,147.101-35.616,189.606-92.854
c45.659-61.482,39.673-120.866-5.028-180.841c-37.314-50.064-126.141-67.693-184.915-80.39
c-90.278-19.498-192.558-10.397-279.444-44.865c-74.021-29.363-167.793-73.691-193.513-156.378
c-17.428-56.03-20.716-143.802,36.015-181.982c58.886-39.631,148.526-40.825,216.305-49.425
c71.297-9.047,146.186-9.725,215.652-23.335c74.498-14.597,140.473-30.115,189.976-93.165
c32.844-41.83,53.193-89.854,24.771-156.016C641.086-13.609,557.179,7.892,440.83,7.892"/>
</svg>
```

Above is my SVG code its simple curve line path.

And my javascript code I want to run, but it draws from middle:

```
var triangle = document.getElementById("triangle");
var length = triangle.getTotalLength();

triangle.style.strokeDasharray = length;

triangle.style.strokeDashoffset = length;

window.addEventListener("scroll", myFunction);
function myFunction() {
var scrollpercent = (document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop) / (document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight);
    var draw = length * scrollpercent;
    triangle.style.strokeDashoffset = length - draw;
}
```

Comment: Hi. Please add a working [mcve] so we can see the problem in action.

Comment: Must be the way you are drawing the triangle. If you want to start from top it's where you have to begin the path. But to be sure you need to add the svg

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/8rGaoxu.png

thats my SVG

Comment: Please add the svg and the javascript code to the question. You need to add them as code. An image of the code won't do

Comment: Added SVG and JS Code

Comment: Hello @enxaneta, added question for that issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make it begin at the top I've reversed the path. I hope this is what you need.

```js
var triangle = document.getElementById("triangle");
var length = triangle.getTotalLength();

triangle.style.strokeDasharray = length;

triangle.style.strokeDashoffset = length;

window.addEventListener("scroll", myFunction);

function myFunction(e) {

var scrollpercent = (document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop) / (document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight);
    var draw = length * scrollpercent;
    triangle.style.strokeDashoffset = length - draw;
}
```

```html
<svg id="route "xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="712px" height="2018px" viewBox="0 0 712 2018" class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">
<path id="triangle" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="5" d="M440.83,7.892C557.179,7.892 641.086,-13.609 694.435,110.574C722.857,176.736 702.508,224.76 669.664,266.59C620.161,329.64 554.186,345.158 479.688,359.755C410.222,373.365 335.333,374.043 264.036,383.09C196.257,391.69 106.617,392.884 47.731,432.515C-9,470.695 -5.712,558.467 11.716,614.497C37.436,697.184 131.208,741.512 205.229,770.875C292.115,805.343 394.395,796.242 484.673,815.74C543.447,828.437 632.274,846.066 669.588,896.13C714.289,956.105 720.275,1015.489 674.616,1076.971C632.111,1134.209 552.072,1152.196 485.01,1169.825C391.941,1194.292 171.09,1138.987 135.326,1268.846C118.85,1328.652 191.327,1381.43 231.544,1409.869C289.505,1450.857 340.832,1469.519 407.393,1487.867C506.477,1515.179 676.052,1568.484 668.852,1697.888C664.962,1767.785 640.197,1814.969 565.581,1829.97C483.849,1846.403 399.726,1847.903 313.914,1847.903C272.363,1847.903 111.43,1863.815 72.315,1887.142C44.71,1903.604 21.879,1925.722 8.64,1955.972C-1.922,1980.108 5.601,2007.223 -3.215,2030.921"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: suppose i want to draw SVG depending on the position of div .
what the JS code??

Comment: I'm not very sure I understand you. You can have a div with `overflow:scroll` and you can listen the scroll on that div. Please ask it as a different question and do not forget to add the code. I would like to help.

Comment: I would like to obtain the same effect in different sections on the page :

Comment: Hello  @enxaneta